# How can I get my dual monitor setup to work on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, 19.04, monitor

I am using a dual boot with Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10, and I cannot get my dual monitors to work in Ubuntu. Here are some important details:

1. My dual monitors work perfectly on Windows 10.
2. Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize my second monitor (see image)
   [Screenshot of my screen display settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QNe0.jpg)
3. During startup, the dual monitors work, except when the monitors turn off after I enter my password, the second monitor does not turn back on.
4. I managed to get the setup to work once, and then break on restart, for unknown reasons. I did not change any settings in between.
5. The monitors also did not work when I was on 18.04 (in fact I upgraded to 19.04 in an attempt to fix it)

I ask that you help me in solving this, using one monitor is torturous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this working? Do you get any errors when you run xrandr?